# Python TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, arrays, firebase

I was having some problem when trying to extract data out from array in Python. I got this array:

```
[array([ 349.11759027]), array([ 306.51289706]), array([ 387.37637654]), array([ 348.15424288]), array([ 386.3088823]), array([ 356.0820971]), array([ 446.37942998]), array([ 394.73726333]), array([ 434.91548947]), array([ 507.92351186]), array([ 435.48301334]), array([ 652.74389728])]
```

I am trying to extract out the value, and then add to firebase. The expected output as such:

```
Jan: 349.11759027
Feb: 306.51289706
Mar: 387.37637654
...
Dec: 652.74389728
```

And my code:

```
month = 0
    for t in p:
           month = month + 1
           result = firebase.post('/profit', {month : t})
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It seems `t` is a `ndarray`, you need to convert it into normal int object.

Comment: My predictions was originally a list()

Comment: @Sraw Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input you mention -

```
[array([ 349.11759027]), array([ 306.51289706]), array([ 387.37637654]), array([ 348.15424288]), array([ 386.3088823]), array([ 356.0820971]), array([ 446.37942998]), array([ 394.73726333]), array([ 434.91548947]), array([ 507.92351186]), array([ 435.48301334]), array([ 652.74389728])]`
```

is a list with each element being a numpy array.
Changing your code to this should work -

```py
for t in predictions:
   month = month + 1
   result = firebase.post('/forecastProfit', {formatMonth(month) : t[0]})
```